# What is the optimal way to execute geospatial queries in Presto using Hive tables?

Tags: geospatial, presto

Presto Geospatial functions supports executing spatial queries.
[Presto Geospatial functions](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/geospatial.html)

I would like to know the optimal way to implement them.

I am trying to implement 3 spatial queries in Presto, using data stored in Hive tables. The implementation of the queries are as follows

**1. Circle range query**:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name WHERE
ST_Intersects(ST_Buffer(ST_Point(x1,y1), radius), ST_Point(x, y));
```

**2. BBOX range query**:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name WHERE
ST_Contains(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON ((x1 y1, x2 y2, .. , x1 y1))'), ST_Point(x, y));
```

**3. k-NN query (k=10)**:

```
SELECT ST_Distance(ST_Point(x1, y1), ST_Point(x, y)) as distance, x, y FROM
table_name ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT 10;
```

Does Presto provide any operator like PostGIS for speeding up k-NN query?

Kindly let me know the optimized way to implement the above queries (especially k-NN).